# Wordpress plugin: ajaxStart conflict in Post page (autosave)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a small plugin which appears in the post page and it has a touch of Ajax.

```
    $("#some-div").ajaxStart(function(){
     $(this).html('Loading...');
    });

    $.post(
        AjaxHandler.ajaxurl,
        { action : 'wt4-cats',  },
        function(response) {                
    //do some stuff
   });
```

thing is that Wordpress triggers the autosave feature every few minutes or so and affects my ajaxStart call. I mean, on autosave the "some-div" html becomes "Loading...". Is possible to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

1) Open your wp-admin/post.php file and wp-admin/post-new.php files.
2) You will find this line of code there:

wp_enqueue_script('autosave');

3) Add // to the beginning of this code.

The autosave option will be disabled for your existing and new posts.

Comment: ... without breaking the autosave functionality apparently

Comment: hmmmm not sure about that! Sorry !